# Jetpack Compose time interval

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm trying to replicate this image component into a Jetpack Compose compatible one. It is a 24 hr time interval, in which according to an array:

```
"timeArray": [ 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 0, 1, 2, 3 ]
```

I must paint in green the hours that are within that range in the array, leaving those hours that are not marked with nothing. On the other hand, the red bar indicates the position of the user's current time.

I tried to realise this component with a Slider or a RangeSlider, but the result was not what I expected. Then I tried to make a LazyVerticalGrid so that there would be 24 Box composables and so I could paint the squares according to the marked times, but I didn't get the final result either.

The expected result would be something like this:

[image: time interval]

Can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: did these list items are static or dynamic?

Comment: @DeePanShu I have a list of items, when I click on one of them, it takes me to the details screen, and when I bring up the service data I get that list of hours. So that list of hours, only changes when I enter the details screen depending on the data that comes from the pressed element. So in principle the list of available hours would be static, what would be dynamic would be the red bar that indicates the current time.

Comment: you have to make a class object which has for example: hourNumber, isBig will be used for 12 hour, isMedium will be used for 6 hour and so on for remaining 2, then make a list of 24 where you define the category for every our and then when the view renders: compare the object.hourNumber with your time array and give the color to that item.